async function as argument to async function
I'm trying to declare an asynchronous function that takes as an argument another asynchronous function that must take an argument by immutable reference
just for an example of what I want to get here is the js code:
async function wrapper(fun) {
    await fun("hello");
}

async function foo(some) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log(some);
}

async function main() {
    await wrapper(foo)
}

main()

and this is what I try in rust:
use std::future::Future;
use tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    wrapper(foo).await
}

async fn wrapper<F, Fut>(fun: F)
where
    F: Fn(&str) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    fun("hello").await;
}

async fn foo(some: &str) {
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    println!("{}", some);
}

the compiler gives this error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
6  |     wrapper(foo).await
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl for<'a> Future<Output = ()>`
              found opaque type `impl Future<Output = ()>`
   = help: consider `await`ing on both `Future`s
   = note: distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/main.rs:11:20
   |
11 |     F: Fn(&str) -> Fut,
   |                    ^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `fnhell` (bin "fnhell") due to 1 previous error

I have a feeling this could be easily fixed but I have absolutely no idea what he's talking about.
addition:
use std::future::Future;
use tokio;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct DataStruct {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    wrapper(foo).await;
}

async fn wrapper<F, Fut>(fun: F)
where
    F: Fn(&DataStruct) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    let data = DataStruct {
        name: "hello".to_string(),
        age: 10,
    };
    fun(&data).await;
    println!("{:?}", data);
}

async fn foo(some: &DataStruct) {
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    println!("{:?}", some);
}



Short answer F: Fn(&'static str) -> Fut, but I assume, you might want it for shorter lifetimes. See also the following question and answer:

The use of generic types complicates the compiler message but the key part is the note: "the lifetime requirement is introduced here". fun takes a string slice (&str) which is a reference to the memory that makes up the string, not the memory itself. If the &str parameter in fun pointed to a String somewhere else in your code, that String could go out of scope, invalidating the &str. Lifetime specifiers don't work well in this case due to the trait bound of F returning Future.
Two simple fixes. The first is changing the parameter type to an owned String and converting the hardcoded static string slice "hello" to String with to_string().
async fn wrapper<F, Fut>(fun: F)
where
    F: Fn(String) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    fun("hello".to_string()).await;
}

async fn foo(some: String) {
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    println!("{}", some);
}

Alternatively, if fun will always take a static string slice, you can change the parameter type to &'static str, which indicates that the string slice can be valid for up to the duration of the program. String literals are always &'static (see Rust Book - The Static Lifetime).
async fn wrapper<F, Fut>(fun: F)
where
    F: Fn(&'static str) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    fun("hello").await;
}

async fn foo(some: &'static str) {
    tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
    println!("{}", some);
}


Thanks for your answer, Fred. But if instead of accepting &str my function accepts &DataStruct, then the only option is cloning? I showed this in an addendum to the question

@Andrey Cloning would be the simplest solution but if the performance cost is unacceptable, you might have to implement a solution with higher-ranked trait bounds similar to the one in the post that vallentin referenced. Since F: Fn(&str) -> Fut, you need to tell the compiler that the lifetime of the future encapsulates the lifetime of the reference.

Actually, if you make foo() take ownership of its parameter, you can avoid cloning and referencing altogether. That's the best option if you don't need the data passed to foo() later.
